# Group by id from the substring queries on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have data from the database, and get the two characters from the id, I do not understand how to calculate data from the substring with the same id?

Example:

> id = AA001, AA002, AA003, AB005, AB006, AC009, AC010, AC012, AC015
>
> Result substring = AA, AA, AA, AB, AB, AC, AC, AC, AC,
>
> I expected = AA:3, AB:2, AC:4

This my controllers

```
function mySubstr() { 
        $data=array('section'   => $this->mSubstr->get_substr(),
                    'isi'       =>'home/substr');
        $this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data); 
 }
```

Models

```
function get_substr() {
    $query = $this->db
            ->select('LEFT(id, 2) as id', FALSE)
            ->from('tbSubstr')
            ->group_by('id')
            ->get();
    return $query->result();   
}
```

Views

```
<?php
    foreach ($section as $row) {
        echo json_encode($row->id); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: is the length of the substring always fixed?  i mean 2?

Comment: @1000111, yes true

Comment: you missed the count portion. pls try this : `SELECT 
LEFT(id,2) AS subst,
COUNT(*) total
FROM tbSubstr
GROUP BY subst`

Comment: i try again and the result fix my problem thanks

Comment: To mark a question as solved, simply click the tick icon adjacent to the answer you most like. It seems that you have already done that, and that is all you need to do.

Comment: @halfer, okay thanks for the advice , I often see a question that says SOLVED I think it signifies that the question has been resolved

Comment: @dwiyanto: it is popular on programming discussion boards, but we don't do that here, mainly because we have a better way of signifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this will may help you,

```
function get_substr() {
   $query = $this->db
        ->select('LEFT(id, 2) as sub_id , COUNT(*)', FALSE)
        ->from('tbSubstr')
        ->group_by('sub_id')
        ->get();
   return $query->result();   
}
```